# Delete rows from different tables in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

A little bit of code-snippet:

```
$this->db->where('id', $outfit_id);
$this->db->update('outfit_main',$data);

//Delete productsettings for specific outfit (They are added below with new values)
$this->db->where('outfit_id', $outfit_id);
$this->db->delete('outfit_products');

//Delete outfit_images for specific outfit as well. They are also added below
$this->db->where('outfit_id', $outfit_id);
$this->db->delete('outfit_images');
```

What I want to do is:

1. Delete rows from outfit_main where id = $outfit_id
2. Delete rows from outfit_products where outfit_id = $outfit_id
3. Delete rows from outfit_images where outfit_id = $outfit_id

But in fact when I add the last two rows:

```
$this->db->where('outfit_id', $outfit_id);
$this->db->delete('outfit_images');
```

***it deletes all rows from outfit_main as well. why?***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try combining the where clause with the delete active record:

```
$this->db->delete('outfit_main', array('id' => $outfit_id));
$this->db->delete('outfit_products', array('outfit_id' => $outfit_id));
$this->db->delete('outfit_images', array('outfit_id' => $outfit_id));
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that, `Ci` is using `old/cached` query for `where` clauses, so if you `flush` to clear the cache using

```
$this->db->flush_cache();
```

And then use

```
$this->db->where('outfit_id', $outfit_id);
$this->db->delete('outfit_images');
```

Then, maybe it'll work in right way.
Check [caching](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#caching) examples, it'll be more clear and I've confusion about it as well, so waiting for response.

Comment: It didn't seem like the "right" approach, I went on doitlikejustin's approach instead. But thanks for your answer!

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld, Thanks, if you don't mind then can you please try my approach for testing so I can be sure about it and maybe I'll delete the answer, just an experiment to verify my understanding, you have a chance to check it.

Answer (score 1):

you might try this. but it wil not work because. codeigniter ignore join while deleting active records.

```
$this->db->join("table2", "table1.thing_id = table2.id")
  ->where("table2.otherthing_id", $id)
  ->delete("table1");
```

you may use the following code to delete data from different tables. It will help you.

```
$sql = "DELETE t1 FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.thing_id = t2.id
  WHERE t2.otherthing_id = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array($id));
```

Answer (score 1):

An array of table names can be passed into delete() if you would like to delete data from more than 1 table. Much Easier way

```
$tables = array('table1', 'table2', 'table3');
$this->db->where('id', '5');
$this->db->delete($tables);
```